# How to calculate threshold values for a simple binary classification model

Tags: binary-classification

Consider a binary classification problem with two features. Let's assume that the higher the value of each feature the more likely a datapoint is to be positively classified.

Additionally assume we can only have a simple model that says: If feature 1 is greater than T1 and feature 2 is greater than T2 then positively classify the datapoint. How do I efficiently find T1 and T2 to obtain a desired False positive rate?

Data might look similar to below:

```
feature 1   feature 2   label
100         0.1         0
120         0.15        0
130         0.2         0
140         0.22        1
150         0.07        0
155         0.06        0
```